# In what ways does SDL add value beyond just graphics?

Tags: sdl, sdl2

I'm in the process of learning SDL. On their webpage, they tout that commercial games (like Valve's Humble Bundle) use the SDL libraries. However, it seems like most of these games have more advanced graphics than what SDL can offer (i.e. only 2D textures).

In what ways do games use SDL if not for their graphics? SDL is primarily "sold" based on its abilities to handle texture writing, but it seems like there are other benefits that I'm not understanding?

Comment: They use it for the other things it provides besides its 2D graphics library? I'm not sure if you are going to get a better answer out of developers who are not said commercial game companies. Especially reasons for using SDL besides anything else would be mostly guesswork.

Comment: When you ask 'how' are you asking with respect to coding or licensing? Regarding why - the general answer is: they find more value in using it than some other solution (either their own code or some other framework). And keep in mind, you can augment a framework like SDL with other solutions (including your own code) to get the features you want.

Comment: We generally can't answer "Why did game X use solution Y". What we *can* help you with is "How can MY game solve problem Z". So: what problem are you using SDL to solve? Where have you run into trouble solving this problem? Edit your question to ask this, and we can respond with answers to help you solve that problem - whether the solution involves SDL or some alternative.

Comment: Where is SDL primarly "sold" as a texture writer? Their own website has a description "Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform development library designed to provide low level access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, and graphics hardware via OpenGL and Direct3D", which lists graphics as last and a bunch of other possible uses for the library.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 most new users to SDL stumble across it from discussion boards as a way to write 2D textures to the screen. However, it seems like SDL can also be used as a standard interface to interact with various other PC systems? To make your program most cross platform capable?